# oracle spring transaction not rolling back

Tags: transactional

```
<bean id    = "transactionManager"
      class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg name = "dataSource"
                     ref="dataSource">
    </constructor-arg>  
</bean> 

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager = "transactionManager"/>


    <bean id    = "dataSource"
          class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name  = "driverClassName"
                  value = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />

        <property name  = "url"
                  value = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl" />

        <property name  = "username"
                  value = "sys as SYSDBA" />

        <property name  = "password"
                  value = "sys" />
    </bean>

    <bean id    = "namedParameterJdbcTemplate"
          class = "org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name = "dataSource"
                         ref  = "dataSource">
        </constructor-arg> 
    </bean>

@Component
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    public TestDao testDao;

    @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public String insert(){
        //testDao.insertUser(107, "Sec");
        testDao.insertUser(101, "Sec");
        testDao.insertUser(100, "Sec");
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

@transactional rollback for exception.class not working.

Got java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint but still not rolling back.  First DAO is executing.